# Can you use "Goldilocks" as an adjective?

Tags: adjectives, modifiers

Space professionals have popularized the terms *Goldilocks planet* & *Goldilocks zone* to describe planets and regions of space around a star that, like earth, are "just right" to conceivably harbor life.

Are there other popular instances of using "Goldilocks" as an adjective? Can I just attach the word to any noun?

Comment: You can't use it before another noun and call it an adjective, but you can use it before another noun (carefully chosen so as to make sense) and call it a 'noun modifier', 'noun adjunct' or 'attributive noun'. Then it is a noun _behaving like an adjective_. Just like 'football' in 'football manager'. But not 'football planet', as far as I know. And 'Goldilocks manager' probably isn't going to work either.

Comment: I've heard it used as a verb as well, ie, with "Just goldilocks it" meaning to set something at an intermediate just-right level

Comment: What's the 3rd person singular form?

Comment: Football Planet sounds awesome :D

Comment: @toryan Well, there is the World Cup, of course.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth  That's easy, 'he, she, it Golidilockses'. What's troubling me is how we translate it into French.   I think it goes je boucle d'ors, tu boucle d'ors, il boucle d'ort, nous boucle d'orons. vous boucle d'orez, ils boucle 'd'orent. I'm having troible with the conditional subjunctive however. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why was 'Goldilocks' chosen for this meaning? What does the possibility of life on an outer planet have to do with a part-eater bowl of porridge?  Is it perhaps part of a suite of words chosen to describe features of outer-space? Are there Red Riding-Hood mountains, and Jack and the Beanstalk vegetation?

Comment: Most people would agree with OP that 'Goldilocks' is just right.

Comment: @WS2: Most "adjectival" usages of *Goldilocks* tend to allude to the *not too hot, and not too cold* aspect (of Baby Bear's porridge). Practically all the others I'm familiar with allude to the more general *not so "extreme" as to be uncomfortable for **humankind*** (but feasibly *comfortable for other life-forms, including certain bears or other extremophiles (either actually alive on Earth now, or hypothetical alien life-forms)*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Right. I get the point! This will make a good bedtime story when I am stumped for one.

Comment: @WS2  I've not heard yet (you could be the first!), but if someone were to describe their garden by saying "...and we had these Jack and the Beanstalk sized broccoli heads this year" I would understand them to mean the broccoli was large.   I think we should start a trend of such once upon a time speech!

Comment: @WS2, for some reason, I feel that _boucle d’or_ as a verb ought to be conjugated as _je boucle d’or, tu boucles d’or, il boucle d’or, nous bouclons d’or, vous bouclez d’or, ils bouclent d’or_. I’m not sure what you mean by conditional subjunctive, though—imperfect subjunctive? If so, it would clearly be _que je bouclasse d’or, que tu bouclasses d’or_, etc.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Noun modifiers. That's a new concept for me. I woulda (still would) accepted that comment as the answer, if it were an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is useful?

[Goldilocks Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldilocks_principle)

It shows examples in cognitive science, medicine and economics.

---

**Edit:**  Been noticing this usage since I answered this question. It really is quite widespread.  Here is a description of a pocket knife:

> It's Goldilocks Knife. It has just enough blades and tools to make it
>   actually useful, while it still feels like a traditional pocket knife.

http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2013/09/favorite-stuff-from-summer/#slideid-199601

Answer (score 1):

In the story of the three bears, Goldilocks was choosy about which of three bowls of porridge she ate from (first was too cold, second was too hot, third was just right) which of three chairs she sat in (first too high, second too broad, third just right), and which of three beds to sleep in (too soft, too hard, just right).

Just last week lexicographer Ben Zimmer wrote a piece in the *Wall Street Journal* called "[How Goldilocks Moved to Space and the World of Economists](http://online.wsj.com/news/articles/SB10001424052702304243904579198083961140464)" which includes:

- Goldilocks principle
- Goldilocks problem
- Goldilocks planet
- Goldilocks zone
- Goldilocks economy
- Goldilocks theory
- Goldilocks market

*Goldilocks* was chosen because a habitable planet is not too close or too far from its star. For example, Venus is too hot, Mars is too cold, but Earth is just right.

This is a noun modifier where the noun *Goldilocks* is acting like an adjective and modifying a noun like *planet*.

It's probably widespread enough to be added to almost any noun with similar qualities to those listed: one that's not too much this, not too much that, but is just right.